# How to track for how long specific item was detected via Android MLKit object detection?

Tags: android, object-detection, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I'm working on specific app that detect items via MLKit (Android),detection works great, but what would be most optimal way to track for how long specific items was detected.

Like if I detect certain item I want to track how long it was detected for (in seconds). So if it was detected for X seconds, I want to invoke certain activity with that)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify STREAM_MODE when building the ObjectDetectorOptions. In that case, for each DetectedObject, you will also get a tracking Id. Then you can check if the same tracking Id is returned from the ObjectDetector for a certain period of time.

ML Kit provides a sample app containing the functionality of triggering certain logic after detecting and tracking an object for a period of time. That app is more involved, but you may take a look for some reference:
https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/material-showcase